# 2nd Activity doesn't call after calling from 1st Activity

Tags: java, android

```
if(dialog.getProgress()==dialog.getMax())
 {    
      Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowMyDialog.class);
         startActivity(i);
 }
```

I have written this code in my 1st activity.but 2nd activity not get called after progress bar value reached to max.
so,please help me......how can i solve this.

Comment: How are you updating the value of the dialog?

Comment: R u getting any error? If so, please mention...

Comment: EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.increment);
        // convert the text value to a integer
        increment = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
 i have taken text box for putting value and written above code....its working but after completing i want to call next activity

Comment: nope no any error..after completing progress bar it stop der beacuse i have written o1.onPause(); where o1 is obj. of class....

Comment: Can you post more codes? Where did you use this code?

Comment: No one is going to answer your question if your are not selecting right answer.

Answer (score 0):

That if statement is only evaluated once - wherever it is declared. In order for that check to be called continuously, you'll need to put it in the same method that updates your dialog box.

Comment: ok...but i have written that code in while....so if i write this code in while den hw it will work??